# Format current time in Google App Scripts

Tags: google-apps-script

How can you set the current time with google app scripts? I'm having a tough time finding the Time documentation.

I'm able to get the time in milliseconds using.

`(new Date()).getTime()`

I'd like to now format this time as 11:56 AM. I'm using the Date [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/contacts/date-field). I've tried using `toLocaleTimeString()` from javascript but it is not defined in app scripts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For formatting a date, what you want is the Utilities.formatDate() function, documented here:  https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#formatDate(Date,String,String)

Usage to get the time only would be:

```
Utilities.formatDate(YOUR DATE,YOUR TIMEZONE, 'HH:mm')
```

replacing YOUR DATE and YOUR TIMEZONE with the appropriate values.